Russian TST 2005- In a 2 x n array we have positive reals such that the sum of the numbers in each of the n columns is 1.
I came across this question in Olympiad Combinatorics by Pranav. Here's the complete problem statement:

In a $2 \times n$ array we have positive reals such that the sum of the numbers in each of the $n$ columns is $1$. Show that we can select one number in each column such that the sum of the selected
numbers in each row is at most $\frac{(n+1)}{4}$.

Here's the solution:

A very trivial greedy algorithm would be to select the smaller number in each column. Unfortunately, this won’t always work, as can easily be seen from an instance in which all numbers in the top row are $0.4$. So we need to be more clever. Let the numbers in the top row in non-decreasing order be $a_1, a_2,..., a_n$ and the corresponding numbers in the bottom row be $b_1, b_2,..., b_n$ (in nonincreasing order, since $b_i = 1 - a_i$). Further suppose that the sum of the numbers in the top row is less than or equal to that of the bottom row. The idea of ordering the variables is frequently used, since it provides some structure for us to work with.
Our algorithm is as follows: Starting from $a_1$, keep choosing the smallest remaining element in the top row as long as possible. In other words, select $a_1, a_2,..., a_k$ such that $a_1 + a_2 +...+ a_k \leq \frac{(n+1)}{4}$ but $a_1 + a_2 +...+ a_k + a_{k+1} > \frac{(n+1)}{4}$. Now we cannot select any more from the top row (as we would then violate the problem’s condition) so in the remaining columns choose elements from the bottom row. We just need to prove that the sum of the chosen elements in the bottom row is at most $\frac{(n+1)}{4}$.
Note that $a_{k+1}$ is at least the average of $a_1, a_2,..., a_k, a_{k+1}$ which is more than $\frac{(n+1)}{[4(k+1)]}$.
Hence $b_{k+1} = (1 - a_{k+1}) < 1 - \frac{n+1}{4(k+1)}$.
But $b_{k+1}$ is the largest of the chosen elements in the bottom row. So the sum of the chosen elements in the bottom row cannot exceed
${(1 - \frac{n+1}{4(k+1)})(n-k)}$.
We leave it to the reader to check that this quantity cannot exceed
$\frac{(n+1)}{4}$.

I'm stuck at the last part here.
Can anyone tell me why/give me a hint, I tried moving everything to one side and completing the square.

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

I do not know where exactly you are stuck, so let us do it from the beginning.
The numbers in the top row are given indices such that
$$a_1 \le a_2 \le \ldots \le a_n \tag{1} .$$
Note that $a_i$ will not necessarily be the entry in column $i$ (but we could exchange the columns to achieve this; such a rearrangement does not affect the problem). Thus the $b_i = 1 - a_i$ satisfy
$$b_1 \ge b_2 \ge \ldots \ge b_n . \tag{2}$$
We shall determine $k \in \{0,\ldots,n\}$ such that both $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i \le \frac{n+1}{4}$ and $\sum_{i=k+1}^n b_i \le \frac{n+1}{4}$. This clearly solves the problem.
In fact, there exists a unique $k \in \{0,\ldots,n\}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i \le \frac{n+1}{4}$ and  $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} a_i > \frac{n+1}{4}$. Note that we may have $k = 0$ (this means $a_1 > \frac{n+1}{4}$) or $k = n$ (this means $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \le \frac{n+1}{4}$). In case $k = n$ we are done, so let us consider $k < n$.
By $(1)$ we have $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} a_i \le (k+1)a_{k+1}$, thus
$$a_{k+1} \ge \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} a_i}{k+1} > \frac{\frac{n+1}{4}}{k+1} = \frac{n+1}{4(k+1)} .$$
Thus
$$b_{k+1} = 1 - a_{k+1} < 1 - \frac{n+1}{4(k+1)} $$
so that by $(2)$
$$\sum_{i=k+1}^n b_i \le (n-k)b_{k+1} < (n-k)(1 - \frac{n+1}{4(k+1)}) = 
((n+1) -(k+1))(1 - \frac{n+1}{4(k+1)}) \\= (n+1) -(k+1) -((n+1) -(k+1))\frac{n+1}{4(k+1)} \\= (n+1) -(k+1) - \frac{(n+1)^2}{4(k+1)} + \frac{n +1}{4} .$$
Setting $p = n+1$ and $l = k+1$ it therefore remains to show that
$$p - l - \frac{p^2}{4l} \le 0 .$$
This is equivalent to
$$l^2 - pl + \frac{p^2}{4} \ge 0 $$
which follows from
$$l^2 - pl + \frac{p^2}{4}  = (l - \frac p 2)^2 .$$
